# AJAX calls in Ionic 2 application

Tags: ajax, cors, ionic2

I have developed a sample ionic 2 application  which runs without any issues in my windows 10 system.
This application also makes cross domain AJAX calls.

I have also created an apk file , and was able to install the apk in my android mobile. But the only problem I am facing is that the mobile app is not able to
make cross domain AJAX calls.

In config.xml I have also included

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
```

and

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

And I have also configured my other application to which this app makes ajax calls for CORS.

Any idea what could be the issue or how to debug it ?

Comment: Did you get any errors after making the AJAX calls ?

Comment: How to check for JS errors in mobile app..?